# line-height not working after change from XHTML1 Trans to HTML5 doctype

Tags: html, xhtml, css

A website that I've been working on was originally created using XHTML 1.0 Transitional - however, since I dislike it, I switched over to the HTML5 doctype.

When I refreshed the page, for some reason there is a subtle shift in the text on the page.

The line-height stops working when it goes under a certain pixel (usually the font-size).
This throws off the visual-alignment of the menu I have set up for logged in users.
For example, if the font-size is set to 14 pixels, `line-height:14px;` will display the same exact thing as `line-height:1px;` when you know 1px should have overlapping text with any font-size over 1px.

You can view a demonstration at [removed, out of date] -> Test login is: TestPile/test. The menu shows up where you login (after you login that is).

Any thoughts on how to get line-height to react as it normally should?

Comment: You need to describe more exactly what you regard as the problem, and you should try to isolate it in a demo that is as simple as possible (preferably, a static page with minimal content). What “subtle shift” are you referring to, how does it relate to “throws off the visual-alignment”, and which exact DOCTYPE did you use previously? (A single typo in a DOCTYPE usually throws browsers to Quirks Mode.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML5 doctype, being the more modern doctype, causes standards mode in browsers. The XHTML 1.0 Transitional doctype causes limited-quirks mode. The behaviour you get with the HTML5 doctype is the correct one, so you are really asking "How do I make line-height behave like it **shouldn't**?". That's going to be difficult.

Here's a description of the differences in line-height calculations between limited-quirks(aka almost standards) and standards modes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff405794%28v=vs.85%29

You will need to embrace the standards mode behaviour and adjust your layouts accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar issue. In quirks mode `<span>` (and other inline elements) can have a smaller line-height than their parent. In HTML5 mode, that does not work the same way. I switched to `<div>` there which will handle the line-height as before. Or you change your inline elements to use `display:inline-block`.